# сумму элементов каждой из строк массива

Tags: c, массивы, функции, указатели, память

Со стандартного устройства ввода в первой строке вводятся 2 целых числа M и N –
соответственно количество строк и столбцов двумерного массива: 1<=M<=100,
1<=N<=100. В следующих M строках вводятся ровно по N элементов – значения
элементов двумерного массива. Все значения в массиве от -100 до 100
Требуется вывести через пробел M чисел, i-ое из которых – это сумма элементов i-й
строки массива A. Выводить пробел в конце строки не нужно.
Sample Input
4 3
1 2 3
5 6 7
3 4 5
4 8 6
Sample Output
6 18 12 18

```
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
 
int tr (int**, int, int);
int main () {
int a[100][100];
    int n,  i, j, m;
int **p;
scanf("%d %d", &m, &n);
for(int i=0; i<m; i++) {
    for(int j=0; j<n; j++) {
            scanf("%d", &a[i][j]);
    }
}
p=(int**)malloc(m*sizeof(int));
p=(int**)malloc(n*sizeof(int));
for(int i=0; i<m; i++)
for(int j=0; j<n; j++)
p[i]=(int*)malloc(m*sizeof(int));
for(int i=0; i<m; i++)
    for(int j=0; j<n; j++)
p[j]=(int*)malloc(n*sizeof(int));
for(int i=0; i<m; i++)
    for(int j=0; j<n; j++)
        p[i][j]=a[i][j];
int t=tr(p,m,n);
for(int i=0; i<m; i++) 
{ 
    printf("%d ", t);
    }

return 0;
}
int tr(int**p, int m, int n) {
    int t, i, j;
    t=0;
        for(int i=0; i<m; i++) 
            for(int j=0; j<n; j++) 
        t+=p[i][j];
        return t;
}
```

Проблема кода в том, что он считает сумму всех элементов массива, а не строк. Как изменить код, чтобы считал сумму элементов именно стро?Еще проблема в том, что надо последний элемент вывести без пробела, скорее всего надо это сделать с помощью if/else или тернарного оператора, но пока нет мыслей как это сделать. Заранее спасибо за помощь

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Может, ограничиться этим? Без всей кучи `malloc`'ов и прочих ненужных вещей?

```
int main()
{
    int M, N;
    scanf("%d %d",&M, &N);
    for(int i = 0; i < M; ++i)
    {
        int sum = 0;
        for(int j = 0; j < N; ++j)
        {
            int k;
            scanf("%d",&k);
            sum += k;
        }
        printf("%d ",sum);
    }
}
```

Ах, да! последний пробел не выводить... Замените `printf` на этот:

```
    printf("%d%s",sum,(i==M-1) ? "" : " ");
```

Answer (score 1):

Немного заморочился. Я думаю примерно так должен выглядеть твой код =) :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

typedef struct {
    int* mtrx;
    int  rows;
    int  cols;
} Matrix;

void scan_number(int* const num, const int min, const int max);
void print_matrix(const Matrix* const matrix, const char* delim);
void randfill_matrix(Matrix* const matrix, const int min, const int max);

int main()
{
    int rows, cols;
    puts("Enter the number of rows:");
    scan_number(&rows,1,100);
    puts("Enter the number of cols:");
    scan_number(&cols,1,100);

    Matrix matrix;
    matrix.rows = rows;
    matrix.cols = cols;
    matrix.mtrx = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int) * rows * cols);

    randfill_matrix(&matrix,-100,100);
    print_matrix(&matrix," ");

    free(matrix.mtrx);
    return 0;
}


void scan_number(int* const num, const int min, const int max)
{
    do {
        scanf("%d",num);
        if (*num >= min && *num <= max)
            break;
        else {
            puts("Failure. Number out of range");
            printf("The range of valid values: [%d;%d]",min,max);
        }
    } while(1);
}

void print_matrix(const Matrix* const matrix, const char* delim)
{
    for (int row = 0; row < matrix->rows; ++row)
        for(int col = 0; col < matrix->cols; ++col)
            printf("%d%s",matrix->mtrx[row*matrix->cols+col],
                          ((col==matrix->cols-1)?"\n":delim));
}

void randfill_matrix(Matrix* const matrix, const int min, const int max)
{
    const int range = max > min ? max - min : min - max;
    const int shift = max > min ? min : max;

    srand(time(NULL));
    for (int row = 0; row < matrix->rows; ++row)
        for(int col = 0; col < matrix->cols; ++col)
            matrix->mtrx[row*matrix->cols+col] = rand() % (range+1) + shift;
}
```